# sed incorrectly strips backslashes

Tags: c, sed

```
find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\// |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"
```

Prints out the directory structure of the current directory, which is what I want. Example:

```
.
 |-one
 |-two
 | |-two_2
 | |-two_1
 |-test_file
```

However, when I put it in an alias file (file with all of my aliases), like so:

```
alias ls_tmp="cd /tmp; find . | sed -e \"s/[^-][^\\/]*\\// |/g\" -e \"s/|\\([^ ]\\)/|-\\1/\""
```

, which is being loaded with the following sed commands:

```
// load alias
  sprintf(buf, "cat %s|grep \"^alias \"| sed -e \"s/=/ /\" | sed -e \"s/\\\\\\\\//g\"", FILE_NAME);
  f = popen(buf, "r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to init alias commands.\n");
    return;
  }
```

, the command actualy executed is actually

```
cd /tmp; find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^/]*// |/g" -e "s/|([^ ])/|-1/"
```

Note that all of the backslashes have been stripped, despite the fact that I escaped the backslashes using //.

How do I make this work? I'm confused as to what

```
sed -e \"s/=/ /\" | sed -e \"s/\\\\\\\\//g
```

does. Maybe it has to do with the \\\\?

Comment: Between alias, sed, and C compiler, there are a lot of places where escaping can operate and remove the slashes. My suggestion: like in the Casino, double your slashes until it works.

Comment: you could consider another way of doing this, because you're waking up 4 or 5 technologies just to do that. A simple python script could do the same and it would work.

Comment: There is a command called `tree` that lists a directory in that hierarchical way.

Comment: I suggest you forget that aliases exist. Almost anything you can do with an alias can be done with a function, and you'll run into fewer problems.

Comment: The sprintf format string `sed -e \"s/\\\\\\\\//g` is stored as the string `sed -e \"s/\\\\//g` because all those backslashes' escaping backslashes in the original string have resolved to just 4. Now the command is run and there are 2 sets of backslashes' escaping backslashes. So `sed` is executing `-e s/\\//g`. I believe `sed` also uses the backslash escape in which case sed is globally substituting every singular backslash with nothing.